# How to use gson parse hetorogeneous map

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I want to parse a sample json by gson like this:

```
"category": {
    "sub_category_1": [...],
    "sub_category_2": [...],
    "sub_category_3": {...}
}
```

Because all sub categories are dynamic and I'm only interested in sub categories which are maps. So I'm using `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` as data type in POJO. However, I got error saying array is expected. My guess is that it's also using that data type to parse when sub category is an array. Any suggestion? I'm new to Retrofit and Gson, so it would be great if you can paste your deserializer code here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a custom `TypeAdapter` for `Gson`. It's a hard and messy job, but it's the only way I found to make the parsing viable. Take a look at these:

http://www.javacreed.com/gson-typeadapter-example/

http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-type-adapter.jsp

https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html